What Adapter or Handle do I need to fix a Handle to Barn Door?
We have a barn-style garage with hinged double barn doors. The right-side door has a pull chain lock mechanism on the inside and a 5/8" (16mm) male hex bolt slightly sticking out of the outside of the door. The other barn door (left) closes inside of the right one. The male hex bolt on the outside of the door seems to be threaded a 1/4" into the bolt. To "unlock" the door from the inside. I have to attach vise-grip pliers to the hex bolt and turn clockwise.
I'm having trouble finding a handle that would fit. I've searched for "(5/8|16mm) hex (lever|handle)". I'm mostly seeing results for double side door handles or handles that have square male bolts. I also tried searching for a "16mm female hex adapter"



This rather looks to me like a jury-rig. I doubt that the bolt was originally part of the turning mechanism for that dual-rotating pull piece inside the door. In fact, the whole thing might have been a cobble-together.
I'd stop looking for a suitable handle for that particular bolt and instead look for a good complete replacement door bolt mechanism.
Meanwhile, a 5/8" offset box wrench on the existing bolt might be a usable handle for now. Tack weld it into place and it may serve for the foreseeable future.

I was half thinking that a full-on replacement would just be easier. Any recommendations to maintain the hole through the door?

I ended up finding a suitable tool-steel machine offset handle online. I plan on making the opening a bit bigger, then brazing it to the hex bolt.


Get a 5/8" socket and a 3/8" drive breaker bar.
